# Reach A Target number only using other two numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, data-structures

I am having two numbers L and R, L means left and R means Right.
I have to get to a certain number(F) using L and R.
Every time i have to start with zero as initial.

Example :
L : 1
R : 2
F : 3

SO minimum number of steps needed to get to F is 3.
Ans : First R, Second R, Third L.

IN this way i need to find the minimum number of ways to do it.

```
My approach:

Quo = F/R;
Remain : F%R;

x*R-Y*L = Remain
==> (x*R - Remain)/L = Y
this equation is break when (x*R - Remain)%L = 0, so we find x and y from the equation above.
So final Steps would be Quo + x(No. of right steps) + y( no. of left steps).

For Above Example :
Quo = 3/2 = 1;
Remain = 3%2 =1;

Y = (x*2 -1)/1
(x*2 -1)%1 is zero for x=1;
Now increase x from zero,

So x is 1, y is 1

Final Ans = Quo (1) + x (1) + y(1) = 3.
```

My code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace  std;

int main()
{
        int F,R,L;
        cin >> F;
        cin >> R;
        cin >> L;

        int remain = F%R;
        int quo = F/R;

        int Right = 0;
        int left = 0;
        int mode = 1;
        while( mode !=0)
        {
            Right++;
         mode = (R*Right - remain)%L;
         left = (R*Right - remain)/L;

        }
        int final = quo + Right + left;
        cout << final;
}
```

But i Don't think it is the good approach as i am putting x in loop which can be pretty costly

Can you please suggest me a good approach to do this question ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Where is your program?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about logic and mathematics.

Comment: Nah, it's a perfectly good question about an algorithm.  It's a programming question.

OP - You are correct in your sizing up the problem as needing to compute a linear combination of x and y (a*x + b*y, where a and b are unknown).  If your "steps" are additions, you'll want to find the unique (if it exists!) values of a and b which are both positive and for which (a+b) is minimum.  For large x, this can be solved much more quickly using the Euclidean algorithm.   Have a read:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm - 4.6 is  how it ties into this problem.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I have added my code. Please suggest if you find some good algorithm for the above question. carey May be it is out of topic but there should be an algorithm.

Comment: (however, it sounds like this is an intro to C++ class and not an algorithms class, so unless you've learned about the EA, that's likely strictly "extra credit")

Comment: Thanks @BadZen i am looking into the Euclidean Algorithm

Comment: @Badzen I'm disagree with you, it is not euclidean, because you could just add R and subtract L so it has one unique best case answer (you could change the steps order but it remain unique like RRL RLR LRR for this question) and I think this unique answer(how much R and how much L we need) could be found with mathematical formula.

Comment: @Ali - "how much R and L we need" are exactly the a and b in the linear combination ax+by as I described above.  You use the Euclidean algorithm to find a and b.   There is no closed form answer (if you disagree with this, please provide one =) ).  The solution may not even exist (L=6, R=15, F=47).

Comment: @BadZen it is correct the solution exist when gcd(R,L) | F and dont exist other wise, but this dont have do anything with what I have said, because I think there is still a close form if there is an answer for given R , L and F.

Comment: @Ali - Ok, how would you find out if gcd(R,L,F) != 1, to know the (strictly weaker) answer to if the solution exists or not?   Hint: it's the Euclidean algorithm that computes the gcd.   If you find a faster way or a closed form, please post it, as you've by your own logic found an O(1) implementation for the gcd()=1 characteristic and fortune & fame will surely follow your discovery...  (honest, it doesn't exist)

Comment: @BadZen it has nothing with gcd(R,L,F) the single condition is gcd(R,L) | F. but I never said there is O(1) solution, all I said is that this question is more mathematic than algorithm I'm just disagree with this question being about algorithm. ( I didnot vote for close, because I think this is a good question for this site, but it is also more mathematics than algorithm I think). I'll be glad if you leave your feed back for my answer :)

Comment: gcd(R,L) | F non-trivially if and only if gcd(R,L,F)!=1. You said you thought there was a closed-form solution ("formula"). If there is, then there is a closed-form formula for determining if gcd(R,L,F)=1, and thus gcd(a,b)=1. I don't know why you believe that there is, but the fact that no human has found one in thousands of years should be persuasive enough. (The best known answer is iterative, a variant of the EA and I believe is of complexity O(ln^2(A)), where a is the smaller of the L,R numbers.)

Comment: @BadZen if you dont want to understand what I'm saying and ignore whatever I say is not my problem, I leave enough comment for you to understand if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the given below equation

```
 x*R - Remain = 0modL
 where R, L and Remain are fixed.
```

It can be written as

```
((x*R)mod L - Remain mod L) mod L = 0
```

If Remain mod L = 0, then x*R should be multiple of L which makes x to 0modL.
Means x can be 0, nR where n is Integer.

So, simply, you can try x between 0 and L-1 to find x.

So, your loop can run from 0 to L-1 which will keep your loop finite.

Please note that this mod is different from %. `-1 mod L = L-1` whereas `-1%L = -1`

There is another approach.

```
x*R mod L - Remain mod L = 0 mod L
```

leads to

```
x*R mod L = Remain mod L
(x* (R mod L)) mod L = (Remain mod L)
```

You can compute inverse of R (say `Rinv`) in field of L (if it does exists) and compute `x = (Remain*Rinv)modL`.
If inverse does not exists, it means equation cannot be satisfied.

Note: I am not mathematical expert. So, please give your opinion if anything is wrong.

See: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/21-127/lectures/congruences_print.pdf

Comment: Computing the inverse uses - you guessed it, the Euclidean algorithm.   Using it directly is faster.  =)

Comment: Nope!  It's essentially the same method. The inverse fails where EA would terminate with a non-unit gcd, and you end up doing one extra multiplication at the end.  I'm not sure if there's an implementation of modular inverse handy in C++ stdlibs though, as there is in Java - so OP would probably have to implement EA anyhow.  If you want me to nitpick on something anyway, I'll tell you that the group you compute the inverse in doesn't have to be a field. =p